# Remove vertical lines in the table unsuccessfully

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, tabularx, revtex

I have created this Table:

[image]

via the LaTex source code:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,amsmath,amssymb,nofootinbib,superscriptaddress,floatfix]{revtex4}   
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!h]
    \begin{tabular}{|c ||c| c| c| c|}  
     \hline
    $(d+1)$D \; & \;  $Z$  & \; $UZ1$ & \; $UZ2$ & \; $U$\\  
                   \; & \;   & \;       \;   & \;       \;   & \;   \\ \hline
    $d=0$         \; & \; 0   & \; 0      \;   & \; $Z$       \;   & \;    \\
                      \; & \;   & \;       \;   & \;  $n \in Z$: $n \int A$     \;     & \;  \\   \hline                 
    $d=1$    \; & \; $Z_2$    & \;       \;   & \;       \;   & \;  \\
                  \; & \;  $S_1=\int x_1{}^2$  & \;       \;   & \;    \;   & \;   \\   \cline{2-5}           
                  \; & \; G  & \;     G  \;   & \; G   \;   & \;  G \\   \hline    
    $d=2$       \; & \;   & \;       \;   & \;     \;   & \;   \\
                      \; & \;   & \;       \;   & \;    \;   & \;   \\   \hline    
     \end{tabular}
    \caption{}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

> **Question**: What I wish is that to join all the G, G, G, G in the d=1 section into one row. That is I wish to **remove the three vertical lines (vline) among four G.** **How to do that?**

I try to use [this method from the previous post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37036/tabular-cline-not-working), but it does not work well. The function I tried is

```
\multicolumn{4}{ l|}{G}
```

which does not work. I use `revtex4`, which should not matter too much.

Thank you, please help!

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: please always post _complete_ documents not fragments, but you want `\multicolumn{1}{c}{G}` for a `G` in a cell without vertical lines

Comment: @ David, That is true, somehow I add this \; which makes trouble to me. With \; then \; \multicolumn{4}{l|}{G        G       G         G} cannot compile successfully. But remove \;, it works.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yeah, I just covered both cases. But deleted the comment one I saw you had provided the solution. So perhaps we should remove _this_ comment and yours above `{1}` not `{4}` as my comment that you are responding to is no longer there.

Comment: `\multicolumn` has to be the _complete_ cell if you did want `\;` it would be `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\;  G\:}`  not with the `\;` outside, but better without them at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
\documentclass{revtex4}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newcommand\Z{\mathbb{Z}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[!h]
\begin{tabular}{|c ||c| c| c| c|}
 \hline
$(d+1) D$  &   $Z$  &  $UZ1$ &  $UZ2$ &  $U$\\
                &   &          &          &   \\ \hline
$d=0$          &  0   &  0        & $\Z$        &     \\
                   &    &           &   $n \in \Z$: $n \int A$          &   \\   \hline
$d=1$     &  $\Z_2$    &           &           &   \\
               &   $S_1=\int x_1{}^2$  &           &        &    \\   \cline{2-5}
               &  \multicolumn{4}{l|}{G        G       G         G} \\   \hline
$d=2$        &    &           &         &    \\
                   &    &           &        &    \\   \hline
 \end{tabular}
\caption{}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of using all those `\;`, if you want some more space, change `\tabcolsep` like

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
```

and put it just after `\begin{table}` so that it is made local.

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
```

Comment: If not give full MWE and more details.

Comment: That is true, somehow I add this \; which makes trouble to me. With \; then \; \multicolumn{4}{l|}{G        G       G         G} cannot compile successfully. But remove \;, it works! Thanks! +1.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\newcommand\Z{Z}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]%never h on its own
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c ||c| c| c| c|}  
 \hline
$(d+1)$D  &   $Z$  &  $UZ1$ &  $UZ2$ &  $U$\\  
         &    &           &           &    \\ \hline
$d=0$   &  0   &  0         &  $\Z$          &     \\
        &    &           &   $n \in \Z$: $n \int A$          &   \\   \hline                 
$d=1$     &  $\Z_2$    &           &        &   \\
         &   $S_1=\int x_1{}^2$  &           &        &    \\   \cline{2-5}           
      &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{G}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{G}&  \multicolumn{1}{c}{G}      & G \\   \hline    
$d=2$        &    &           &         &    \\
     &    &           &        &    \\   \hline    
 \end{tabular}
\caption{zzz}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```